# c# negation operator open parenthesis expected

Tags: c#, parentheses, negation

In C#, I'm writing code for negation operator like this, but it show `syntax error, '(' expected`

```
DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
var col = tmp.Columns;
if !(col.Contains("COL1") && col.Contains("COL2") && col.Contains("COL3"))
{
    //DO STH
}
```

If I change to this code the error disappear:

```
DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
var col = tmp.Columns;
if (!col.Contains("COL1") || !col.Contains("COL2") || !col.Contains("COL3"))
{
    //DO STH
}
```

[Docs from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) seems too simple and I didn't find how to correct the first code.

So why the first code has syntax error, and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: you should put `if` *condition* in parenthesis: `if (any condition here)`

Comment: The **syntax** for `if` is `if (expression)`, those parenthesis are not optional.

Comment: You can also use a helper variable. when the expression is too long or complexe simply store it in a variable `var constainsTheColumns = col.Contains("COL1") && col.Contains("COL2") && col.Contains("COL3");` and negate that: `if (!constainsTheColumns){`. The overhead is just one bool on the stack. But it may help readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

an if always starts with a ( so the code should be

```
DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
var col = tmp.Columns;
if (!(col.Contains("COL1") && col.Contains("COL2") && col.Contains("COL3")))
{
    //DO STH
}
```